# Manipulating excel 2007 chart grid lines in VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, vsto, excel-2007

Using Excel 2007, is it possible to change the transparency of chart grid lines using VBA or VB.NET?

I have the following code, which throws an exception on the last line:

```
Dim axis As Excel.Axis = chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory)
axis.HasMajorGridlines = True
axis.MajorGridlines.Border.Color = Color.Gray.ToArgb
axis.MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
axis.MajorGridlines.Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.8
```

( Of course, this code is in VB.NET )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of your code, I think it should be

```
axis.MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Transparency = 0.8
```

That works for me and adjusts the transparency of the vertical gridlines.

Comment: This works except you have a small typo, the correct method is:

  axis.MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Transparency = 0.8

( Notice that the Format.Lines has become Format.Line )